# i just started a blog, but no site builders seem to edit the homepage

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Please someone assist me, i just started this site [cfa24.com](https://cfa24.com/2023/10/10/how-much-is-infinix-smart-5/), i've edited every other page with Elementor, nut the homepage is not saving my updates

homepage should be editable, just like every other page, please anyone with useful tip is welcomed